# Google API to discover third party app access

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

Google Admin Console allows us to manage third-party App Access Control for OAuth apps registered and used for SSO. Is there an API to discover this list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Reports API, method [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22applicationName%22%3A%22token%22%2C%22eventName%22%3A%22authorize%22%7D).

You can try the following example with Apps Script, this script will retrieve the list of the third-party apps.

```js
function appAccessControl() {
  var eventName = {
    "eventName": "authorize"
  };

  var appsList = [];
  var response = AdminDirectory.Activities.list("all", "token", eventName);

  for(var i=0; i< response.items.length; i++)
  {
    if(appsList.includes(response.items[i].events[0].parameters[1].value)==false)
    {
      appsList.push(response.items[i].events[0].parameters[1].value);
    }
  }
  console.log(appsList);
}
```

**Note:** To run this script you need to add the "Admin SDK API" service in your Apps Script project, on the left side of the screen, click on the “+” next to “Services”, search for “Admin SDK API”, select "reports_v1" from "Version", and click “Add”.

Comment: Thanks, @lorena, I was suspecting the same, as I could query the reporting API to get some data, but I assume is based on user activity so not a foolproof approach. Thanks for the help